# Can not load library Qt5Widgets.dll

Tags: qt, dll, qt5

[Error when run FBLTool_0224.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeoCU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

installing visual C++ 2010 runtime x86 solved problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you double-clicked in exe file that provides after building in release mode :
For Deploy and create Exe output with QT in windows you should follow this way:

1. put your compiler path in your system path. now you use mingw81_64 you should set it. something like  `Qt/tools/mingw81_64/bin`
2. copy exe file that provides after building in release mode in one folder and run mingw81_64 cmd (it has separate cmd)
   and cd to that folder path
3. `windeployqt  app.exe`

**This command will get all dll needs for your app and your exe will work .**

if you use qml

```
windeployqt --qmldir (the path of its directory ) app.exe
```

and also see these youtube videos for more info:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LdSTgR0xJco

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hCXAgB6y8eA